# File content returns [object Object] after download Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, download

I'm trying to download different files from some URLs (.txt, .js, .json, etc), when I download something from .js or .json (possible other extension), the content when I open the file is `[object Object]`

I'm using this function in Reactjs to download the specified file from the URL

onClick:

```
<div className="messageFile" onClick={() => handleDownloadFile("http://localhost:5000/storage/example.json", "example.json")}>
    Download File
</div>
```

Function:

```
function handleDownloadFile(url, name){
   const formatedURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([{url}]));
   const link = document.createElement('a');
   link.href = formatedURL;
   link.setAttribute('download', name);
   document.body.appendChild(link);
   link.click();
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you sure that you send your file correctly from backend?

Comment: Yes, in backend the file is saved correctly and when I try manually to access the file via URL `http://localhost:5000/storage/example.json` it shows the correct content of the file @Konrad, the problems seems to be from frontend when I try to download the file from the specified URL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with `[object Object]` is because you pass the url as an object into the array.

This will download a json file but the content will be the url

```
function handleDownloadFile(url, name){
    const blob = new Blob([url], {type: "application/json"});
    const formatedURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = formatedURL;
    link.setAttribute('download', name);
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
}
```

so in order to download the json file with the correct content you need to read the file content first

```
//.......
let data = "your_file_content_here";
const blob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(data)], {type: "application/json"});
// ......
```

for text files use `{type: "text/plain"}` instead.

to make your **json file** readable you need to use `JSON.stringify(data, null, "\t")` the third parameter `"\t"` means **Indented with tab** this will give a readable json file

```
let data = { "name": "John doe","age": "33"};

function handleDownloadFile(data, name){
    const blob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(data, null, "\t")], {type: "application/json"});
    const formatedURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = formatedURL;
    link.setAttribute('download', name);
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
}


handleDownloadFile(data, 'example.json');
```

Comment: Thanks! Is working. But one more question. It seems that the objects are not having spaces, like they are on a single line: {"id":1,"name":"Test","time":239232}. How can I make the object to be more readable (with spaces) like the original file that was sent?

Comment: @Galbert pass the data as it is, without using JSON.stringify. see the edited Answer

Comment: It doesn't work, if I don't use JSON.stringify, I get again: [object Object]. Anyway. I fixed this by using: `JSON.stringify(data, null, 4)`

Comment: @Galbert does JSON.stringify(data, null, "\t") solve your problem?

Comment: @Galbert exactly, 4 means 4 spaces and "\t" means intended with tab.  i missed that part anyway i updated my solution